# NuGet downgrade warning

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin.Android and I want to know how to work on this issue in Visual Studio

What does this warning mean?

> Warning   NU1605   Detected package downgrade:  Xamarin.Forms from
>   4.2.0.848062 to 4.2.0.709249. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.   App1.Android -> App1 ->
>   Xamarin.Forms (>= 4.2.0.848062)   App1.Android -> Xamarin.Forms (>=
>   4.2.0.709249) App1.Android    C:\Users\Synergy Mobile App 1\source\repos\App1\App1\App1.Android\App1.Android.csproj

Comment: Did you read documentation? This helps for start.

Comment: This is a NuGet error. Your two projects reference the Xamarin.Forms NuGet packages of a different version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Let's start with [documentation of this warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605)***

**What can help you get rid of this warning**

Check if you all your project have reference to the same Xamarin.Forms version.

In order to do that:

1. Expand your Core
2. Go to `Dependendencies` -> `Nuget`
3. Look for `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package
4. When you find it, in the bracket you will have its version

Repeat the steps for your Xamarin.Android project.

If the versions are not the same update the one that is lower, so they are the same.